# angular js pushing data into list is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a Json list which I'm saving in angular js score var

```
 $scope.jobTemplate = [{ type: "AddInstructions", visible: false, buttonText: "Add Instructions", editableInstructionsList: [{ Number: totalEditableInstruction, Text: "Instruction 1"}] },
    { type: "AddSingleQuestionsList", visible: false, buttonText: "Add Ques. (single Ans.)", singleQuestionsList: [{ Number: totalSingleQuestionList, Question: "What is your gender ?", Options: "Male1;Female2"}] },
    { type: "AddMultipleQuestionsList", visible: false, buttonText: "Add Ques. (Multiple Ans.)", multipleQuestionsList: [{ Number: totalMultipleQuestionList, Question: "What is your multiple gender ?", Options: "Malem1;Femalem2"}] },
    { type: "AddTextBoxQuestionsList", visible: false, buttonText: "Add Ques. (TextBox Ans.)", textBoxQuestionsList: [{ Number: totalTextBoxQuestionList, Question: "Who won 2014 FIFA World cup ?", Options: "text"}] },
    { type: "AddListBoxQuestionsList", visible: false, buttonText: "Add Ques. (ListBox Ans.)", listBoxQuestionsList: [{ Number: totalListBoxQuestionList, Question: "What is your multiple gender ?", Options: "Malem1;Femalem2"}] }
];
```

I'm pushing the data on click of button as follows

```
 // single questions..
$scope.InsertSingleQuestionRow = function () {
    totalSingleQuestionList = totalSingleQuestionList + 1;
    var singleQuestionsList = { Number: totalSingleQuestionList, Question: $('#SingleQuestionTextBoxQuestionData').val(), Options: $('#SingleQuestionTextBoxAnswerData').val() };
    $scope.jobTemplate[1].singleQuestionsList.push(singleQuestionsList);
    refreshSingleQuestionsList();
}
```

though in the UI the newly added item is showing properly but when I'm trying to send the current scope variably data through http post to server, it is not having the latest data.

```
$scope.ClientCreateTemplateFunction = function () {
    var clientCreateTemplateData =  $scope.jobTemplate;          
    var url = ServerContextPah + '/Client/CreateTemplate';        
    if (true) {
        //startBlockUI('wait..', 3);
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: clientCreateTemplateData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
            //stopBlockUI();

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.showErrors = true;
        showToastMessage("Error", "Some Fields are Invalid !!!");
    }

}
```

I tried making global variable too. I've not idea why scope variable is working fine with UI and not working while sending the same data to server through http post.
help me.

I've attached one snapshot where in UI it is showing two list while when I console.log the same scope variable it is showing only one list.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `not having the latest data`? Did you set a breakpoint at the point before firing a http request and found that $scope.jobTemplate isn't up to date?

Comment: I've uploaded the uploaded the snapshot.

Comment: What happens if you added the third item?

Comment: even after adding third item it shows only 1 item that is manually added in the json at the top. rest whatever we add later is now shown.

Comment: It seems there is not enough information at the moment to figure out what is the problem. Could you try to set up a plunker or jsfiddle, so we can reproduce the problem and help you with a debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.ClientCreateTemplateFunction = function() {
  var clientCreateTemplateData = $scope.jobTemplate;
  var url = ServerContextPah + '/Client/CreateTemplate';
  if (true) {
    //startBlockUI('wait..', 3);
    $http.post(url, $scope.jobTemplate).then(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(data, status, headers, config) {
      //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
      //stopBlockUI();
    };   

    function onError(data, status, headers, config) {};

  } else {
    $scope.showErrors = true;
    showToastMessage("Error", "Some Fields are Invalid !!!");
  }

}
```

Comment: Still having the same issue :(

Comment: can you please create plunker or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant send a javascript custom object in post method use jquery's `param` to convert object to string or convert in to `JSON`

```
 $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param( clientCreateTemplateData, true );
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
            //stopBlockUI();

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
```

Comment: From the [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http): *By default, Angular applies these transformations: ... If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.* So no, jquery is neither needed or recommended.